# устройство типа int в python3

Tags: python-3.x, memory

https://habrahabr.ru/post/193890/
На этой странице описано, как устроен тип int в python2. Однако, как я понял, в python3 он устроен иначе - вместо 24 байт занимает 28 и содержит 4 числа, а не 3. Только вот я не понял, что эти числа у него значат.

Comment: После беглого просмотра статьи могу сказать, что нужно смотреть определение структур PyObjectInt и PyObject_HEAD в исходниках Python3.

Comment: В чём у вас вопрос?  `int` в Питоне неограничен (поэтому 4 числами не обойдётесь). Если интересно как CPython это реализует можно посмотреть на [тип `PyLongObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longintrepr.h)

Comment: @jfs А в этом файле этот тип не определяется.

Comment: @insolor А не знаете, в каком из файлов это определяется?

Comment: @DimaVoronetskiy когда нужно я клонирую репозиторий и запускаю поиск по содержимому. Сейчас посмотреть не смогу.

Comment: `struct _longobject` и `PyLongObject` это одно и то же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, я разобрался. Инт хранится следующим образом:
первое число типа long - количество ссылок на объект
второе - id типа объекта
далее собственно число, хранимое в нескольких числах типа int, а перед ними третье число - собственно количество этих чисел.
Спасибо большое @insolor и @jfs за помощь.